# Terminal - highlighted text problem

Tags: pantheon-terminal

i have this problem: when i create some directory, especially the external hard disk directory, my terminal highlights the name of every directories, like this:

[image]

how can i erase those highlight?

Elementary os 0.4.1 Loki

Comment: Use "ll" or "ls -al", you will see this directories have more permissions than normal one. Compare the permissions with the ones of home directorie

Comment: Thank you very much! That was the issue! Thank you again :)

Comment: @kenorb done ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ll` or `ls -al` shell commands, you will see this directories have more permissions than normal one. Compare the permissions with the ones of home directories.